# Jest : TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs

The application is written by React with [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) so `import` and `export` statements are used inside the application. So Jest is configured to work compatible with ES6, but compiled *node_modules* dependencies are causing an error which is

> TypeError: require(...) is not a function

when tests started.

I assume this is happening because Jest configured to work with babel-jest to handle `import` statements, but compiled codes are using `require` for handling the modules. I tried to exclude **node_modules** folder, but nothing changed. I think, ES6 modules using compiled modules placed into the node_modules as a dependency because of that it cannot be excluded? Is it possible?

Also, I am having a problem to understand how does jest handle both `import` and `require` at the same time? If ES6 codes are compiled first then each module will be handled as `require` after that compiling process. So what is the problem?

Here are the configurations

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js",
    "\\.(css|scss|sass|less)$":
      "<rootDir>/mocks/styleMock.js"
  },
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/"
  ]
};
```

**babel.config.js**

```js
/* eslint-disable */
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          browsers: ["ie >= 9", "safari >= 8"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      { loose: true }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ],
  env:{
    test:{
      plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
          { loose: true }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
      ]

    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, actually I did. Babel test environment needs to be configured. Also  `ignorePatterns` and `transform` can be needs some arrangement in `jest.config.js`

https://gist.github.com/oyilmaztekin/f649ce4635fb72c280ea3fae07a24cb9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are tying to import any file for example a font file, then simply create a mockFile that just have

```
// mockFile.ts or mockFile.js
export default {};
```

and then in jest.config.js

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.(woff2)$': '<rootDir>/<path to file>/mockFile.ts',
  },
```

This will resolve to the mockFil when it will try to import a font file. You can also add other file extentions like `'^.+\\.(jpg|png|woff2)$: '<rootDir>/<path to file>/mockFile.ts'`.
It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Follow-up on Aamir Iqubal's answer, I was having the problem with `@sentry/react-native`, jest was failing. I created a `sentryMock.js`

It was failing in my file where I had an import like so:

```js
import { captureException } from '@sentry/react-native';
```

I have `test` folder in my root directory. So, that's what I had to add to `jest.config.js`

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
  '@sentry/react-native': '<rootDir>/test/__mocks__/sentryMock.js',
},
```

In `sentryMock.js`

```js
export const captureException = jest.fn();
```